# How to set up this belongs_to association in Rails / ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration, associations

I have `User` and `Review` models. A review can have an `author` and a `subject`, both pointing to a `User`:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: 'User', optional: true
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', optional: true
end   
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.references :subject
      t.references :author
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine and now I can assign two separate `User` objects to the `Review` object to represent who wrote the review against whom.

The user though, doesn't "know" how many reviews he's associated with either as a subject or the author. I added `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` on reviews and vice-versa, and though doable, isn't exactly what I want.

How do I set up the associations to be able to do the following:

```
review.author = some_other_user
review.subject = user2
another_review.author = some_other_user
another_review.subject = user2

user2.a_subject_in.count
#=> 2
user2.a_subject_in
#=> [#<Review>, #<Review>]
some_other_user.an_author_in.count
#=> 2
```

## In other words, how do I see how many times a `User` has been saved as an author or subject for a model with `belongs_to`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you want to use `has_many` association on users side, you need to define two separate `has_many` relations like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :subject_reviews, class_name: 'Review', foreign_key: :subject_id
end
```

Now with this you can simply use

```
irb(main):033:0> s.reviews
  Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Review id: 1, comment: "random", subject_id: 2, author_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-12 01:16:23", updated_at: "2016-07-12 01:16:23">]>
irb(main):034:0> s.subject_reviews
  Review Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."subject_id" = ?  [["subject_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Comment: *subject_reviews* is not a good name :), change it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this query:

```
class User
  def referenced_in
    # this fetches you all the reviews that a user was referenced
    Review.where("reviews.author_id = :user_id OR reviews.subject_id = :user_id", user_id: id).distinct
  end
end

User.first.referenced_in #should give you all records a user was referenced
```